# How to write to line 10?

Tags: perl, shell, sed, awk

I need a script that can write text to an exsisting file starting on line 10. It is a blank line so it wont be a find / replace. Would like preferably it to be in bash, but anything that the terminal can interpret will work just fine.

```
RE-EDITED:
```

---

Sorry but still having a bit of a problem after I tested... Think it has something to do with what I want write to a file. Maybe this will make it easier..

```
  3 c
  4 d
  5 e
  6 f
  7 g
  8 h
  9 i
 10      zone "$zone" in {
 12          type master;
 13          file "/etc/bind/db.$zone";
 14   };
 15 k
 16 l
 17 m
```

Thanks in Advance,
Joe

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using `sed`:

```
sed -i -e '10a\
new stuff' file
```

Using `bash`:

```
IFS=$'\n'
i=0
while read -r line; do
    i=$((i+1))
    if test $i -eq 10; then
        echo "new stuff"
    else
        echo "$line"
    fi
done <file >file.tmp
mv file.tmp file
```

Note that I'm not really sure if you mean insert at line 10 or at line 11, so double check the places I wrote `10` above.  You might want `9` for the `sed` command or `11` for the `bash` version.

In `perl`, you can use the `$NR` variable.

```
open FILEHANDLE, "<file";
while (<FILEHANDLE>) {
    if ($NR == 10) {
        # do something
    }
}
```

And in `awk`, it's `NR`.

```
awk 'NR != 10 { print }
NR == 10 { print "Something else" }' file
```

---

But note that you can find and replace a blank line, e.g.

```
sed -i -e 's/^$/replacement text/' file
```

Comment: thanks I can see sed looks to be much easier... and yes insert at line 10 since there is already text on line 9 and 11.

Comment: Sure.  It'll only work on Linux, FreeBSD, Mac OS, and Cygwin.  On Solaris, AIX, HP-UX, etc. you'd need GNU sed installed, or to redirect output to a tempfile then `mv` it.

Comment: Exactly.  `perl -p -i -e ...`.

Answer (score 2):

You could just do:

```
head -10 fileA > fileB; echo "new text" >> fileB;
```

Note that this is fractionally quicker than doing it with `sed`

Answer (score 2):

With sed:

```
sed '10 s/^/text' file >file.new && mv file.new file
```

With gnu-sed:

```
sed -i '10 s/^/text' file
```

With awk:

```
awk 'NR==10 {$0="text"} 1' file >filen.new && mv file.new file
```

Comment: That's why I wrote "with gnu-sed" :)

Answer (score 1):

```
sed 10cFoobar foo
```

replaces line 10 with "Foobar". This may contain line breaks:

```
sed 4cFoobar"\nFoobar" foo
```

This is in contrast to Mikel's solution who used a instead of c. The difference is that one replaces, the other one appends.

Answer (score 0):

If the file already has 9 lines, it would be easy on the shell ;)

```
$ echo "I am line 10" >> file-with-9-lines.txt
```

If the file may contain less than 9 lines or even may be larger (and you still want to write into line 10) the perl modul [Tie::File](http://www.p3rl.org/Tie%3a%3aFile) will make things realy easy:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Tie::File;
tie my @file, 'Tie::File', '/path/to/some/file' or die $!;
$file[9] = "I am the content of line 10";
```

Comment: @Mikel sorry I was having problems and erros so I re-edited... Thanks for so many quick responses.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby (1.9+)

```
$ ruby -i.backup -ne 'print ($.==10)?"word\n":$_' file
```